# Tampermonkey: Hide Options in Dropdown if they don't contain a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, tampermonkey

I am working on a Tampermonkey script to make life a lot easier. So picture this: There's a dropdown supplying 400+ options. However, I only need to use two of them. So all the others can be hidden.

So how do I do this? Currently, I am working with this, but it doesn't really do what I want it to.

```
var firstCampaignName = "001 - Campaign";
var secondCampaignName = "002 - Campaign";
```

These are the two options I want to keep. I halfway think I could simplify this by matching them both on " - Campaign" or something. Because the names are nigh-identical. But anyway. So here's the function I'm working with.

```
  $('#dropdown option').each(function(){
    if ('#dropdown option'.text() === firstCampaignName || '#brand option'.text() === secondCampaignName)
    {
        if ($.inArray($(this).text()))
            $(this).show();
        // If not, hide it
        else
            $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

It's obvious that I'm doing something wrong. Somewhere in this, I am missing something. So, please, help?

Comment: Missing `$()` in the `if` to wrap the selector and certainly not using `$.inArray` as documented. You need a search value and an array ....you are only providing a search value. Are you not getting errors thrown in browser dev tools console? Turn on debugging if not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide all options from the dropdown except the 2 specific options you can do the following. Note that as mentioned as comment by charlietfl that to hide options is not supported cross browser, so maybe it's an option for you to remove those options instead of hiding them as you mentioned that you don't need them.

```js
var firstCampaignName = "001 - Campaign";
var secondCampaignName = "002 - Campaign";
$('#dropdown option').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() === firstCampaignName || $(this).text() === secondCampaignName) {
    $(this).show();
  } else {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="1">001 - Campaign</option>
  <option value="2">002 - Campaign</option>
  <option value="3">003</option>
  <option value="4">004</option>
  <option value="5">005</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Should note that hiding `<option>` not supported cross browser

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the feedback, I'll add this to the answer.

Comment: It only needs to work on Chrome. And it does. So thank you two! I've been sweating over this for about three hours and it stopped making sense to me. Like, all of it stopped making sense. Cheers!